# Is there a simple characterization of ordinals that cannot be "escaped"?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

The ordinal $\omega$ is inescapable, in the sense that for any $N \in \omega$ it holds that if $f : N \rightarrow \omega$ is a function, then the supremum (taken in the class of ordinals) of the range of $f$ is an element of $\omega$.

Is there a simple characterization of the ordinals that, like $\omega$, are inescapable in this sense?

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are talking about [regular cardinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_cardinal) (recall that every cardinal is also an ordinal; an initial ordinal).  These are the (infinite) cardinals $\kappa$ which have the property that any subset $A \subseteq \kappa$ of cardinality $< \kappa$ is bounded in $\kappa$.  (Actually, they are usually defined in terms of [*cofinality*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality), which would result in an almost tautological assertion.)

Note that if $\alpha \in \kappa$ and $f : \alpha \to \kappa$, then the range of $f$ has cardinality $< \kappa$, and so is bounded in $\kappa$.

In general, $\omega$ and all successor cardinals are regular.  An uncountable regular limit cardinal is called a [*weakly inaccessible cardinal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal), and their existence cannot be proven from ZFC.

---

***Added:*** One can show that only cardinals can have your property of inescapability.  If $\alpha$ is not a cardinal, then its cardinality $| \alpha |$ is strictly less than $\alpha$, and there is a bijection $f : | \alpha | \to \alpha$.  Clearly the range of $f$ is not bounded in $\alpha$.

Comment: So $\beth_n$ is regular for all $n \in \omega$, but $\beth_\omega$ is not regular?

Comment: @user18921: Actually, $\beth_n$ may not be regular.  Note that $\beth_1 = 2^{\beth_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ and it is consistent that this is not regular (it just needs to have _uncountable_ cofinality). ($\aleph_n$ will be regular, however; and $\aleph_\omega$ will not be.)  $\beth_\omega$ will not be regular (being the limit of the $\beth_n$).

Comment: Wow, really? So there exists $A \subseteq \beth_\omega$ with $|A|<\beth_\omega$ such that $A$ is unbounded in $\beth_\omega$? What's an example of such an $A$, and what is its cardinality?

Comment: @user18921:  Recall that $\beth_\omega = \sup_{n < \omega} \beth_n$, and so $\{ \beth_n : n < \omega \}$ is a countable subset of $\beth_\omega$ which is unbounded in $\beth_\omega$.

Comment: Oh yeah! Wow, I never realized how crazy these numbers are.